# Accessing durance of hate without killing SuperUnique council members

Tags: diablo-ii

Will the quest "The Blackened Temple" be completed by killing the 6 ordinary council members, and then enter the Durance of Hate without killing all 3 superunique Council members?

I am asking because in Hell mode, some of them have 120 lightning resist and it is near impossible for me to kill them with a lightning character on single player.

I seem to see this speedrun player manage to do just that (skipping Toorc Icefist altogether)

.

Can anyone confirm that the superunique do not count towards the quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quest completes when you smash the compelling orb and the Durance of Hate opens. The quest tells you to kill the council because any of the three council members can have the Flail needed for the crafting recipe.

In multiplayer, if someone has a waypoint or is already in the Durance of Hate, you can NOT take a town portal until you have killed the three council members and completed the quest.

Single player -> Find the flail and smash the orb, don't need to kill all 3 council members

Multiplayer -> Kill all 3 council members and get a waypoint TP

The reason Llama doesn't fight all of the them is because the speedrun concludes when Baal is defeated, not completing all quests. He runs the Any% category of Diablo II.